# Planck's Law 3D Plot with units outputting blank graph

Tags: plotting, physics, units

I'm trying to plot Planck's Law for black body radiation on a wavelength-temperature graph where the output (z-axis) is the intensity. The function has multiple variables so I tried Plot3D.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law#Different_forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Different_forms)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Subscript[B, 1][λ_, T_] := 
 2 Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"] Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]^2 / Quantity[λ, "Meters"]^5 * 
 1/(Exp[Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"] Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"] / (Quantity[λ, "Meters"] Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"] Quantity[T, "Kelvins"])] - 1)

Plot3D[Subscript[B, 1][Quantity[λ, "Meters"], Quantity[T, "Kelvins"]], 
 {λ, 0, 3*10^(-6)}, {T, 0, 1000}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

This is the first time I'm trying to use units with the Quantity function, but I can't seem to get the output to show anything...

Any help is appreciated as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot can be obtained with the following changes to the plot statement:

```
Plot3D[QuantityMagnitude@Subscript[B, 1][λ, T],
 {λ, 0, 3*10^(-6)}, {T, 0, 1000},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

However, it plots faster in the following version:

Substituting SI values for the quantities, and using simple variable names.

First obtaining the physical constant values.

```
entities = EntityValue[EntityList[
    EntityClass["PhysicalConstant", "SIExact"]],
   {"Symbol", "Name", "Value"}];

{h, c, k} = N[QuantityMagnitude@*Last /@ Lookup[Association[Thread[
       entities[[All, 1]] -> entities]], {"h", "c", "k"}]]
```

> {6.62607015*^-34, 2.99792458*^8, 1.380649*^-23}

Then using the OP's function with substitutions.

```
b[λ_, t_] := 2 h c^2/λ^5 * 1/(Exp[h c/(λ k t)] - 1)

Plot3D[b[λ, t], {λ, 0, 3*10^(-6)}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in `PlanckRadiationLaw`:

```
Plot3D[PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[T, "Kelvins"], 
  Quantity[\[Lambda], "Meters"]], {\[Lambda], 10^(-9), 3*10^(-6)}, {T, 10^(-3), 1000}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]